# Set certain values of grouped variable in Highcharter bar plot to be deselected by default

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, bar-chart, r-highcharter

I would like certain values of my grouped variable in a stacked Highcharter barplot to be deselected by default. I know that with `hc_add_series` I can set `visible = FALSE` but I am not generating my chart in that way.

Here is a sample data set:

```
responses <- c('Pro','Against','Neutral','Resigned/Accepting','Not Specified')
constituents <- c('dual degree','law only','undergrad only','friend','parent only')
indiv <- rep(1:50)
Name.Change <- sample(responses,50,replace = TRUE)
constituent.type <- sample(constituents,50,replace = TRUE)

demo <- as.data.frame(cbind(indiv,Name.Change,constituent.type))
```

And here is the chart

```
demo %>% 
  group_by(constituent.type,Name.Change) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  hchart(type = "bar",
         hcaes(y = count,
               x = constituent.type,
               group = Name.Change)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "percent")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

The chart generated has all values of `Name.Change` selected and each value can be deselected as desired. However, I want certain values (e.g. "Neutral" and "Not Specified") to be deselected by default, such that after the chart is rendered, you would have to click that value in the legend in order for it to appear on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to do it with chart.events.load, then you can write your own custom JS function for this:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Here you can see how to do it:

```
responses <- c('Pro','Against','Neutral','Resigned/Accepting','Not Specified')
constituents <- c('dual degree','law only','undergrad only','friend','parent only')
indiv <- rep(1:50)
Name.Change <- sample(responses,50,replace = TRUE)
constituent.type <- sample(constituents,50,replace = TRUE)
demo <- as.data.frame(cbind(indiv,Name.Change,constituent.type))
demo %>% 
  group_by(constituent.type,Name.Change) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  hchart(type = "bar",
         hcaes(y = count,
               x = constituent.type,
               group = Name.Change)) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
  var chart = this;
  chart.series[1].setVisible(false)
  chart.series[2].setVisible(false)
  }"))) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "percent")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, although I had to trial-and-error the index on `chart.series[]` because it didn't correspond to my ordered factor variable or legend order. Not a big deal, I just wonder how chart.series is being indexed based on the `group =` input.

Comment: Without delving into the R code, it depends on the configuration and the way/order of the data provided. Highcharts simply indexes successive points making an array of them in JS, so you have to choose the right ones.